# Optimistic multiIndex query to get min of maximum of all indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, aws-elasticsearch

I am learning elastic search and need help with multiindex search query.

So basically I have 7 indexes. Every index has lastUpdatedDate with every document. Now I want to query all selected indexes at once and get minimum of maximum of last updated date.

eg

index - "A" last updated on 20th Dec - max of all lastUpdatedDate records - 20th Dec
index - "B" last updated on 18th Dec - max of all lastUpdatedDate records - 18th Dec
index - "C" last updated on 19th Dec - max of all lastUpdatedDate records - 19th Dec

min of all these three indexes is 18th.

I can make query to all indexes separately from my backend service, but thinking of optimise query in Java to index all these indexes at once.

One more example:

```
Index-A {
Id:1, lastUpdatedDate: 15th Dec;
Id:2, lastUpdatedDate: 16th Dec;
Id:5, lastUpdatedDate: 15th Dec;
Id:6, lastUpdatedDate: 20th Dec;
};



Index-B{
Id:1, lastUpdatedDate: 21st Dec;
Id:2, lastUpdatedDate: 16th Dec;
Id:5, lastUpdatedDate: 15th Dec;
Id:6, lastUpdatedDate: 20th Dec;
};

Index-C{
Id:1, lastUpdatedDate: 22nd Dec;
Id:2, lastUpdatedDate: 16th Dec;
Id:5, lastUpdatedDate: 15th Dec;
Id:6, lastUpdatedDate: 20th Dec;
}
```

Now max of indexes are:

```
Index-A -> 20th Dec
Index-B -> 21st Dec
Index-C -> 22nd Dec
```

Then min is 20th Dec

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple query would be this one. Retrieve the max updated value per index and then retrieve the bucket with the minimum value in all those buckets:

```
GET _all/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "all_indexes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_updated": {
          "max": {
            "field": "lastUpdatedDate"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "min_updated": {
      "min_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "all_indexes>max_updated"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need min(max(lastUpdatedDate)), updated question.